# Python console pong game - multithreading

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pygame, pong

I am writing a pong game in Python that uses voice input to move the paddles.
I have implemented multithreading so that the google speech recognition module can always run in a separate thread from the main game. However, it doesn't seem to be running on the separate thread and I have no way of finding out how. I want to improve the code so that it can run the speech recognition on a separate thread and stop the game from hanging.

I am also open to any other criticism of the code provided here (readability, clarity, organization, etc).

#### Here are the imports and global variables

```py
# native imports
import math
import random
import pyglet
import sys
from playsound import playsound
from gtts import gTTS
import pyttsx3
import os
# speech recognition library
# -------------------------------------#
# threading so that listenting to speech would not block the whole program
import threading
# speech recognition (default using google, requiring internet)
import speech_recognition as sr
# -------------------------------------#

# pitch & volume detection
# -------------------------------------#
import aubio
import numpy as num
import pyaudio
import wave
# -------------------------------------#

quit = False
debug = 1

# pitch & volume detection
# -------------------------------------#
# PyAudio object.
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
# Open stream.
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=1, rate=44100, input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=1024)
# Aubio's pitch detection.
pDetection = aubio.pitch("default", 2048,
                         2048//2, 44100)
# Set unit.
pDetection.set_unit("Hz")
pDetection.set_silence(-40)
# -------------------------------------#

# keeping score of points:
p1_score = 0
p2_score = 0

r = sr.Recognizer()
```

#### Here is the method for voice input

```py
def listen_to_audio():
    # speech_thread.start()

    results = None

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("[speech recognition] Say something!")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
        try:
            # for testing purposes, we're just using the default API key
            # to use another API key, use `r.recognize_google(audio, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")`
            # instead of `r.recognize_google(audio)`
            recog_results = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(
            "[speech recognition] Google Speech Recognition thinks you said \"" + recog_results + "\"")
            results = recog_results

        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            results ="Unknown Value error! Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio"
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            results = "Request error! Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e)
        
    return results
```

#### Here is the code for gameplay

```py
def main():
    class Ball(object):

        def __init__(self):
            self.debug = 0
            self.TO_SIDE = 5
            self.x = 50.0 + self.TO_SIDE
            self.y = float(random.randint(0, 450))
            self.x_old = self.x  # coordinates in the last frame
            self.y_old = self.y
            self.vec_x = 2**0.5 / 2  # sqrt(2)/2
            self.vec_y = random.choice([-1, 1]) * 2**0.5 / 2


    class Player(object):

        def __init__(self, NUMBER, screen_WIDTH=800):
            """NUMBER must be 0 (left player) or 1 (right player)."""
            self.NUMBER = NUMBER
            self.x = 50.0 + (screen_WIDTH - 100) * NUMBER
            self.y = 50.0
            self.last_movements = [0]*4  # short movement history
            # used for bounce calculation
            self.up_key, self.down_key = None, None
            self.move_up, self.move_down = None, None
            if NUMBER == 0:
                self.up_key = pyglet.window.key.W
                self.down_key = pyglet.window.key.S
                self.move_up = "up"
                self.move_down = "down"
            elif NUMBER == 1:
                self.up_key = pyglet.window.key.O
                self.down_key = pyglet.window.key.L
                self.move_up = "forward"
                self.move_down = "backward"


    class Model(object):
        """Model of the entire game. Has two players and one ball."""

        def __init__(self, DIMENSIONS=(800, 450)):
            """DIMENSIONS is a tuple (WIDTH, HEIGHT) of the field."""
            # OBJECTS
            WIDTH = DIMENSIONS[0]
            self.players = [Player(0, WIDTH), Player(1, WIDTH)]
            self.ball = Ball()
            # DATA
            self.pressed_keys = set()  # set has no duplicates
            self.quit_key = pyglet.window.key.Q
            self.speed = 6  # in pixels per frame
            self.ball_speed = self.speed  # * 2.5
            self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT = DIMENSIONS
            # STATE VARS
            self.paused = False
            self.i = 0  # "frame count" for debug

        def reset_ball(self, who_scored):
            """Place the ball anew on the loser's side."""
            if debug:
                print(str(who_scored)+" scored. reset.")
            self.ball.y = float(random.randint(0, self.HEIGHT))
            self.ball.vec_y = random.choice([-1, 1]) * 2**0.5 / 2
            if who_scored == 0:
                self.ball.x = self.WIDTH - 50.0 - self.ball.TO_SIDE
                self.ball.vec_x = - 2**0.5 / 2
            elif who_scored == 1:
                self.ball.x = 50.0 + self.ball.TO_SIDE
                self.ball.vec_x = + 2**0.5 / 2
            elif who_scored == "debug":
                self.ball.x = 70  # in paddle atm -> usage: hold f
                self.ball.y = self.ball.debug
                self.ball.vec_x = -1
                self.ball.vec_y = 0
                self.ball.debug += 0.2
                if self.ball.debug > 100:
                    self.ball.debug = 0

        def check_if_oob_top_bottom(self):
            """Called by update_ball to recalc. a ball above/below the screen."""
            # bounces. if -- bounce on top of screen. elif -- bounce on bottom.
            b = self.ball
            if b.y - b.TO_SIDE < 0:
                illegal_movement = 0 - (b.y - b.TO_SIDE)
                b.y = 0 + b.TO_SIDE + illegal_movement
                b.vec_y *= -1
            elif b.y + b.TO_SIDE > self.HEIGHT:
                illegal_movement = self.HEIGHT - (b.y + b.TO_SIDE)
                b.y = self.HEIGHT - b.TO_SIDE + illegal_movement
                b.vec_y *= -1

        def check_if_oob_sides(self):
            global p2_score, p1_score
            """Called by update_ball to reset a ball left/right of the screen."""
            b = self.ball
            if b.x + b.TO_SIDE < 0:  # leave on left
                self.reset_ball(1)
                p2_score += 1
            elif b.x - b.TO_SIDE > self.WIDTH:  # leave on right
                p1_score += 1
                self.reset_ball(0)

        def check_if_paddled(self):
            """Called by update_ball to recalc. a ball hit with a player paddle."""
            b = self.ball
            p0, p1 = self.players[0], self.players[1]
            angle = math.acos(b.vec_y)
            factor = random.randint(5, 15)
            cross0 = (b.x < p0.x + 2*b.TO_SIDE) and (b.x_old >= p0.x + 2*b.TO_SIDE)
            cross1 = (b.x > p1.x - 2*b.TO_SIDE) and (b.x_old <= p1.x - 2*b.TO_SIDE)
            if cross0 and -25 < b.y - p0.y < 25:
                playhit = threading.Thread(target=hit(), args=())
                playhit.start()
                hit()
                if debug:
                    print("hit at "+str(self.i))
                illegal_movement = p0.x + 2*b.TO_SIDE - b.x
                b.x = p0.x + 2*b.TO_SIDE + illegal_movement
                angle -= sum(p0.last_movements) / factor / self.ball_speed
                b.vec_y = math.cos(angle)
                b.vec_x = (1**2 - b.vec_y**2) ** 0.5
            elif cross1 and -25 < b.y - p1.y < 25:
                playhit = threading.Thread(target=hit(), args=())
                playhit.start()
                hit()
                if debug:
                    print("hit at "+str(self.i))
                illegal_movement = p1.x - 2*b.TO_SIDE - b.x
                b.x = p1.x - 2*b.TO_SIDE + illegal_movement
                angle -= sum(p1.last_movements) / factor / self.ball_speed
                b.vec_y = math.cos(angle)
                b.vec_x = - (1**2 - b.vec_y**2) ** 0.5


    # -------------- Ball position: you can find it here -------

        def update_ball(self):
            """
                Update ball position with post-collision detection.
                I.e. Let the ball move out of bounds and calculate
                where it should have been within bounds.

                When bouncing off a paddle, take player velocity into
                consideration as well. Add a small factor of random too.
            """
            self.i += 2  # "debug"
            b = self.ball
            b.x_old, b.y_old = b.x, b.y
            b.x += b.vec_x * self.ball_speed
            b.y += b.vec_y * self.ball_speed
            self.check_if_oob_top_bottom()  # oob: out of bounds
            self.check_if_oob_sides()
            self.check_if_paddled()

        def update(self, move_options):
            """Work through all pressed keys, update and call update_ball."""
            pks = self.pressed_keys
            if quit:
                sys.exit(1)
            if self.quit_key in pks:
                exit(0)
            if pyglet.window.key.R in pks and debug:
                self.reset_ball(1)
            if pyglet.window.key.F in pks and debug:
                self.reset_ball("debug")

            # -------------- If you want to change paddle position, change it here
            # player 1: the user controls the left player by W/S but you should change it to VOICE input
            p1 = self.players[0]
            p1.last_movements.pop(0)

            # if p1.up_key in pks and p1.down_key not in pks:  # change this to voice input
            if p1.move_up in move_options and p1.move_down not in move_options:
                p1.y -= self.speed
                p1.last_movements.append(-self.speed)
            # elif p1.up_key not in pks and p1.down_key in pks:  # change this to voice input
            elif p1.move_up not in move_options and p1.move_down in move_options: 
                p1.y += self.speed
                p1.last_movements.append(+self.speed)
            else:
                # notice how we popped from _place_ zero,
                # but append _a number_ zero here. it's not the same.
                p1.last_movements.append(0)

            # ----------------- DO NOT CHANGE BELOW ----------------
            # player 2: the other user controls the right player by O/L
            p2 = self.players[1]
            p2.last_movements.pop(0)
            # if p2.up_key in pks and p2.down_key not in pks: # change this to voice input
            if p2.move_up in move_options and p2.move_down not in move_options:  
                p2.y -= self.speed
                p2.last_movements.append(-self.speed)
            # elif p2.up_key not in pks and p2.down_key in pks: # change this to voice input
            elif p2.move_up not in move_options and p2.move_down in move_options:  
                p2.y += self.speed
                p2.last_movements.append(+self.speed)
            else:
                # notice how we popped from _place_ zero,
                # but append _a number_ zero here. it's not the same.
                p2.last_movements.append(0)

            self.update_ball()
            label.text = str(p1_score)+':'+str(p2_score)


    class Controller(object):

        def __init__(self, model):
            self.m = model
            # self.move_options = None
        
        def listen(self):
            self.move_options = listen_to_audio()
            return self.move_options
            

        def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
            # `a |= b`: mathematical or. add to set a if in set a or b.
            # equivalent to `a = a | b`.
            # XXX p0 holds down both keys => p1 controls break  # PYGLET!? D:
            self.m.pressed_keys |= set([symbol])

        def on_key_release(self, symbol, modifiers):
            if symbol in self.m.pressed_keys:
                self.m.pressed_keys.remove(symbol)

        def update(self):
            self.m.update(self.listen())


    class View(object):

        def __init__(self, window, model):
            self.w = window
            self.m = model
            # ------------------ IMAGES --------------------#
            # "white_square.png" is a 10x10 white image
            lplayer = pyglet.resource.image("white_square.png")
            self.player_spr = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(lplayer)

        def redraw(self):
            # ------------------ PLAYERS --------------------#
            TO_SIDE = self.m.ball.TO_SIDE
            for p in self.m.players:
                self.player_spr.x = p.x//1 - TO_SIDE
                # oh god! pyglet's (0, 0) is bottom right! madness.
                self.player_spr.y = self.w.height - (p.y//1 + TO_SIDE)
                self.player_spr.draw()  # these 3 lines: pretend-paddle
                self.player_spr.y -= 2*TO_SIDE
                self.player_spr.draw()
                self.player_spr.y += 4*TO_SIDE
                self.player_spr.draw()
            # ------------------ BALL --------------------#
            self.player_spr.x = self.m.ball.x//1 - TO_SIDE
            self.player_spr.y = self.w.height - (self.m.ball.y//1 + TO_SIDE)
            self.player_spr.draw()


    class Window(pyglet.window.Window):

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            DIM = (800, 450)  # DIMENSIONS
            super(Window, self).__init__(width=DIM[0], height=DIM[1],
                                        *args, **kwargs)
            # ------------------ MVC --------------------#
            the_window = self
            self.model = Model(DIM)
            self.view = View(the_window, self.model)
            self.controller = Controller(self.model)
            # ------------------ CLOCK --------------------#
            fps = 30.0
            pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0/fps)
            # pyglet.clock.set_fps_limit(fps)

        def on_key_release(self, symbol, modifiers):
            self.controller.on_key_release(symbol, modifiers)

        def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
            self.controller.on_key_press(symbol, modifiers)

        def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
            # XXX make more efficient (save last position, draw black square
            # over that and the new square, don't redraw _entire_ frame.)
            self.clear()
            self.controller.update()
            self.view.redraw()


    window = Window()
    label = pyglet.text.Label(str(p1_score)+':'+str(p2_score),
                            font_name='Times New Roman',
                            font_size=36,
                            x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2,
                            anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')


    @window.event
    def on_draw():
        # window.clear()
        label.draw()


    

    if debug:
        print("init window...")
    if debug:
        print("done! init app...")
    pyglet.app.run()

speech_thread = threading.Thread(target=listen_to_audio, args=(), name="Speech Thread")
speech_thread.start()
# -------------------------------------#
spoken_voice_thread = threading.Thread(target=SpeakText, args=(), name="Spoken voice thread")
spoken_voice_thread.start()
# pitch & volume detection
# -------------------------------------#
# start a thread to detect pitch and volume
microphone_thread = threading.Thread(target=sense_microphone, args=(), name="microphone thread")
microphone_thread.start()
# -------------------------------------#
```

#### Code to implement multithreading

```py
speech_thread = threading.Thread(target=listen_to_audio, args=(), name="Speech Thread")
speech_thread1 = threading.Thread(target=listen_to_audio, args=(), name="Speech Thread")
speech_thread.start()
speech_thread1.start()
```